# Spark: operations outside of mapping flow not executed?

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda

I have some Java code in a spark project that looks like this:

```
public void analyze(JavaRDD<String> rdd) {
  List<String> matches = new LinkedList<>();
  rdd.map(s -> {
    if (isStringValid(s)) {
        SerializableFunction<String, String> func = (s) -> {
          matches.add(s);
          return s;
        }
        return sendStringMsg(s, func);
    }
    return 0d;
  }).mean();
  sendCombinedMessage(matches);
}

double sendStringMsg(String s, SerializableFunction<String, String> callBack) {
   if (send(s)) {
      callBack.apply(s);
      return 1d;
   }
   return 0d;
}
```

where `SerializableFunction<>` is a self-defined functional interface that extends serializable, and `sendCombinedMessage(List<String>)` is a separate method to combine a list of string and send the combined string to a different service. But as I test it, the list of string "matches" seems to always be empty, even if the send() method returns boolean (confirmed from the other service that message is received.)

I found a way to work around this (not very elegantly), but I would appreciate if anyone can give me some insight on why in this case the serializable function is not properly executed, thus making the list empty.

Thanks in advance!